# syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have the code below, and when i load it i always get this error..

```
function newPlayer($wallet) {
  generate_: {
    $hash=generateHash(32);
    }
  if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='$hash' LIMIT 1"))!=0) goto generate_;
      $alias='Player_';
      $alias_i=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `autoalias_increment` AS `data` FROM `system` LIMIT 1"));
      $alias_i=$alias_i['data'];
      mysql_query("UPDATE `system` SET `autoalias_increment`=`autoalias_increment`+1 LIMIT 1");
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `players` (`hash`,`alias`,`time_last_active`,`server_seed`) VALUES ('$hash','".$alias.$alias_i."',NOW(),'".generateServerSeed()."')");
      header('Location: ./?unique='.$hash.'# Do Not Share This URL!');
      exit();
}
```

The error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/a1180044/public_html/inc/functions.php on line 49
```

Line 49 is generate_:

Comment: PHP is not javascript

Comment: What's the role of `generate_:`?

Comment: Are you on an ancient PHP version by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to not use goto, as much as you can.

By using goto you will be lost in your own code, because you have to search each time where your goto is pointing.

Here you can do what you want by writing :

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='$hash' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
    $hash=generateHash(32);
}
```

Comment: Oh god, The `goto` statement was after the scroll in the horribly indented codeblock in OP. @OP yeah don't.

Comment: Thanks for that. I replaced all my gotos and it's fine now. Thanks :)